# How to render PDF into a Python3 PySide application?

Tags: pdf, python-3.x, pyside

Is there a way to display a PDF file into a Python3 PySide application?

python-poppler-qt4 seems to be only for Python 2, and for PyQt.

Comment: From https://code.google.com/p/python-poppler-qt4/: *"Python 3 is not yet tested but it'll probably work out of the box."*

Comment: However, the binding is for PyQt, and I didn't manage to compile it.